# Using VBA to send each record set to a new line in multiLine PDF text box

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am trying to send each recordset to a new line within the text box on a PDF. Im using Access 2016 and i have my reference set for my vba. what is the best way to do this. It enters one record set and that is it. i have the properties set for the text box in the pdf set to multi line. here is the code im using to loop through the recordsets.

```
Dim rs1 As Recordset
Dim SQL1 As String
Dim AcroApp As Acrobat.CAcroApp
Dim PDoc, PDocFil As Acrobat.CAcroPDDoc
Dim PDFSaved As Variant
Dim jso As Object
Dim Fld13 As Object
Dim Output

Set Fld13 = jso.getField("ListofLOAs")
SQL1 = "SELECT tbl_Delegation_Tracker.SignerEmail, tbl_Delegation_LOA_Tracker.LOAFUNDCENTER, tbl_Delegation_LOA_Tracker.LOAFUND, tbl_Delegation_LOA_Tracker.LOAPM, " _
    & "tbl_Delegation_LOA_Tracker.LOATDC, tbl_Delegation_LOA_Tracker.LOASAG, tbl_Delegation_LOA_Tracker.LOAMDEP, tbl_Delegation_LOA_Tracker.LOAMDEPTITLE " _
    & "FROM tbl_Delegation_Tracker INNER JOIN tbl_Delegation_LOA_Tracker ON tbl_Delegation_Tracker.[SignerEmail] = tbl_Delegation_LOA_Tracker.[SIGNEREMAIL] " _
    & "WHERE ((tbl_Delegation_Tracker.SignerEmail) = '" & Forms!Frm_Delegation.Form!SignerEmail & "') "
Set rs1 = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(SQL1)

If rs1.RecordCount > 0 Then
    rs1.MoveFirst
        Do Until rs1.EOF
            Output = rs1!LOAFUNDCENTER & " " & rs1!LOAFUND & " " & rs1!LOAPM & " " & rs1!LOATDC & " " & rs1!LOASAG & " " & rs1!LOAMDEP & " " & rs1!LOAMDEPTITLE
            Fld13.Value = Output & vbNewLine
        rs1.MoveNext
        Loop
End If
```

I have found some things about the `"\r"` and the `"\n"` for new line options in adobe. im just not sure how to write that in for vba. any help is greatly appreciated. Also the `vbCrLf` doesnt work either.

Comment: Output is reset each time, needs to be `output=output & rs1.....`  or you could look at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ado/reference/ado-api/getstring-method-ado?view=sql-server-ver15 `GetString`

Comment: giving that a try. thanks for the feedback. hold one.

Comment: You will need to set the value of Fld13 after the loop also

Comment: that worked thank you. i used your ```output =  output & vbCrLf & rs1.......``` and it works beautifully. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Nathan_Sav comment i entered `Output = Output & vbCrLf & rs1......` inside the loop and this worked perfectly.
Thanks Nathan_Sav

Comment: No probs.  Glad to help.